# Platform-dependent issue in run-length encoding of bmp files using C

Tags: c, encoding, ubuntu, fedora, run-length-encoding

I've written a program which opens a bmp file and treats it as a character file and performs run length encoding on it. It produces a valid compressed encoding file, which I read again to perform the decoding.

When i'd made the application i was using Fedora and it ran perfectly fine. Now i'm running it on ubuntu and it refuses to work.

Any idea what is wrong? I fear it has to do with the encoding.

Comment: Have you tried re-compiling it on Ubuntu or did you just copy the binary across?

Comment: i tried both ways none of them worked..

Comment: That should be something trivial. Like signed/unsigned char by default. Why treat a binary file as a charecter file in the first place?

Comment: How else i can treat the data if not in char? I need to find the continous occurance of a character. What data type may i compare if i read in binary mode?

Comment: That's not the problem of the data type, but how you work with it. Some code snippets would be helpful.

Comment: can you point me to a sample snippet? where i can read each byte of the file?

Comment: You can use read() to read a file. But it's also important that you open the file in binary mode. And it's important what exactly you then do with the data. An error with data manipulation can lead to the problems you experience. So you should provide here the code snippets that you suspect guilty.

Comment: what if i do while(fread()), and advance file pointer to each byte. How can i read the byte it is pointing to currently?

Comment: yeah i know that. It opens in binary mode by default but i'l have to typecast it to char to read a byte right?

Comment: Well, you will read is successfully, but then it all depends on what you do next.

Comment: @sharptooth, on linux there is no difference between byte mode and character mode, that's a win32 thingy.

Comment: @Anirudh Goel, what doesn't work? Doesn't the app start, does it crash or is the output incorrect?

Comment: @Anirudh Goel: Discussing it in terms of "it's not working" will lead use to nowhere. It'll be more productive if you detect waht parts of your code work inproperly and cite them here and restate the question so that it's more focused.

Comment: @Anriudh Goel: Some code would be helpful. Also, what's not working? Encoding the file on Ubuntu? Decoding the file on Ubuntu that you encoded on Fedora? Encoding AND decoding on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I would first and foremost suggest using a source code debugger to find the problem.

Possible causes include using different compilers on the different systems, which might do different things with, for example, packing structs (e.g., BITMAPFILEHEADER).  You also might have different CPU architectures on the two systems (64- vs. 32-bit).

You can also use a hex editor (e.g., XVI32) to examine the differences between BMP files generated by the two versions of your program.